# Can't see CAPTCHA on mobile browser

Tags: support, status-bydesign, captcha

Is there a point I reach with reputation where it no longer asks me CAPTCHA on new devices?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?, Or was my answer sufficient?

Comment: @Rowland: Your answer did indeed answer my question.  I gave up on trying to access it from my phone.

Comment: wanted to make sure - might be worth mentioning on http://meta.stackoverflow.com with details of the device you use -- I've been able to use the site using PocketIE on a Windows Mobile, as well as using Opera on a phone, so it *may* just be your browser of choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still see the captcha occasionally on other sites based on the same software where I have a reputation score over 8,500.